# Assume that $F$ is a field such that $GL_n(F)$ is a divisible group. Is it true that $F^*$ is divisible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Assume that  $F$ is a field such that $GL_n(F)$ is a divisible group. Which means that for any $A\in GL_n(F) $ and any natural number $m$, there exists $B\in GL_n(F)$ such that $B^m=A$. Is it true that  $F^*$ is divisible?

Comment: Do you mean for all $n$? Because $GL_1(F)\simeq F^{\times}$.

Comment: Usually, divisible groups are assumed to be *abelian*, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group). For non-abelian divisible groups see also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90441/non-abelian-divisible-groups).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the determinant map $GL_n(F) \to F^\times$.  This is a surjective group homomorphism, and quotients of divisible groups are divisible.

Comment: Is what really true? That quotients remain divisible? Unless I'm totally missing something I think that's pretty clear. Take some $g \in G/H$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and choose a lift $\tilde{g} \in G$. By the divisibility assumption $\exists \tilde{a} \in G$ such that $\tilde{a}^m = \tilde{g}$. It follows that the image $a$ in $G/H$ of $\tilde{a}$ in G satisfies $a^m  = g$. This can be done for any $g$, $m$ so $G/H$ is divisible.

Comment: Very good. The question only came up because often divisible groups are assumed to be abelian. And not all statements of (abelian) divisible groups remain true for non-abelian divisible groups.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \textrm{Diag}(x,1,...,1)$.  If $B$ is a matrix such that $B^m = A$, then $(\textrm{Det } B)^m = \textrm{Det } A = x$.